# How can I generate a random sequence of numbers in JavaScript with conditions?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate a sequence of numbers from 1-7. Completely random. A number cannot have a number in front of it or behind that separates it by 1.

An example: [2, 4, 1, 6, 3, 7, 5]
NOT: [**5, 4**, 2, **6, 7**, 1, 3].
Also, ***a number cannot have the number of it's position*** (NOT: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]).

Even if I've stated all of these conditions in the while loop, it leaves the loop without fulfilling all of the conditions. And I need some help to figure out what the problem is/a better way to do it.

```
var randomOrder = [];

for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    randomOrder[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    if (i > 0) {
        while ((randomOrder.lastIndexOf(randomOrder[i], i - 1) != -1) && (((randomOrder[i - 1] - 1) != randomOrder[i]) && ((randomOrder[i - 1] + 1) != randomOrder[i]) && (randomOrder[i] != (i + 1))) {
            randomOrder[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        }
        alert(randomOrder.lastIndexOf(randomOrder[i], i - 1));
        alert(randomOrder);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very very expensive operation seems to me.

Comment: @Jai Running this code would take less than a millisecond on any modern device. Micro-optimizing this would be just a waste of time.

Comment: I think you have to do the while conditions the other way round. while(randomOrder[i]!=(i+1)) runs until it got [1,2,3...]. So you want: while(randomOrder[i]==(i+1) OR ...).

Comment: Just wondering--is there a realworld use case for this?

Comment: @Whothehellisthat Haha, yeah. It's for a project. It's very useful, I promise :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a brute force approach:

```js
var list = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ];

while(
  list.findIndex(function(v, i) {
    return v == i + 1 || (i && Math.abs(list[i - 1] - v) == 1);
  }) != -1
) {
  list.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; });
}
document.write(list.join(' '));
```

**Alternate version**

Below is an attempt at the 'progressive filling' method.

It's more efficient overall, in the sense that it's actually trying to build a valid array rather than just observing that a given array is valid. It includes a test for inextricable situations, in which case it will abort immediately.

`build()` succeeds ~66% of the time (empirical results), so the average number of attempts is **1.5**.

By comparison, my first method generates **~27** arrays in average before finding a valid one.

```js
function build() {
  var remaining = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ],
      res = [],
      candidate,
      n, sz, sel;

  for(n = 0; n < 7; n++) {
    candidate = remaining.filter(function(v) {
      return v != n + 1 && (!n || Math.abs(res[n - 1] - v) != 1);
    });
    if(!(sz = candidate.length)) {
      return false;
    }
    res.push(sel = candidate[(Math.random() * sz) | 0]);
    remaining.splice(remaining.indexOf(sel), 1);
  }
  return res;
}

while((list = build()) === false) {};
document.write(list.join(' '));
```

Comment: @jai : use the above.. this one is what you are expecting.

Comment: @Thennarasan Jai is not the OP, though ^^

Comment: This is a really nice solution to the problem

Comment: An interesting way of doing things in the alternate version. Pretty hard to parse it all out into what's actually going on, but I figured it out in the end! ;P

Not sure how much more efficient it is, to make all those extra arrays, though.

Comment: I'd be interested to run a jsPerf with all our efforts, just out of curiosity. But... is jsPerf just straight-up dead or what?

Comment: Yes, jsPerf was closed as a consequence of [too much spam polluting their database](https://github.com/jsperf/jsperf.com/issues/18#issuecomment-113569132). They're working on a v2.

Comment: added a better description of the alternate method and more details on the results

Comment: @Arnauld : Thanks a lot for all your help! As a JavaScript-beginner I had a hard time figuring out what was actually happening in the first version. Since I want to understand the logic of this I would really appreciate a quick explanation of what each part of the code does.

Comment: `list.findIndex` iterates on each item of `list` and invokes a callback function with v = value of item and i = position of item. If the callback function returns true -- namely if the position of an item doesn't fit our conditions -- findIndex will stop iterating and return the position of this item. If the callback never returns true, findIndex will instead return -1. So, the while loop goes on until all items have a valid position. `list.sort` also iterates on each item of the list and invokes a callback function whose returned value is used to sort the list, here in a random manner.

Comment: @Arnauld Why do you have to use "||" since both conditions should be fulfilled? Why is the .abs() necessary? How does the "a && b == c" work? Why do you have to take -0.5 of the Math.random?

Answer (score 0):

Outline of the approach I would consider:

For each position calculate the possible set of numbers at that position, and randomly select from that list.

Position 0 the set would be [2...7], at position 1 it would be [1, 3...7] minus those removed due to the selection at position 0.

If this fails restart from the beginning until it doesn't (it fails if the set of possibilities at a position is empty).

Comment: This is what I would have done, but I think the solution provided by @arnauld is nicer

Comment: @ChrisLear I agree: in the end there is no easy non-brute force way, and simple wins.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue was using && (AND) instead of || (OR).

```
var result = [], current, last = Infinity, i;
while (result.length < 7) {
  i = 0;
  while(++i < 1000 && (!current || result.includes(current) || (current === last - 1) || (current === last + 1) || (current === result.length))) {
    current = 1 + (Math.random() * 7) | 0; // use your floor of choice
  }
  if (i >= 1000) { result.length = 0; continue; }

  result.push(current);
  last = current;
}
```

Comment: And while this code should work, it'll get slower and slower as time goes on, so you may need to optimize it up.

Comment: This allows duplicate values

Comment: There's now a new (more serious) problem, which is that it can get into a situation (eg 6,3,4,5,7,2,...) where there's only one choice for the last digit, and that choice is invalid. It then loops forever.

Comment: Ah! Yes, I thought it was my slow laptop, but I think you're right. I'll work on a solution...

Comment: @ChrisLear Yes, that's the problem with the iterative approach. Actually, you may be stuck after just 4 iterations if you end up with something such as `[6, 4, 7, 2]`. None of the remaining values (1, 3, 5) can be put after the '2' : 2 - 1 = 1, 3 - 2 = 1 and 5 can't be put on the 5th position.

Comment: @Arnauld: Agreed. Though I'm not sure there's any other way. Even your method is iterative beneath the surface.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat True. What I really meant was 'progressive filling' approach, rather than 'iterative approach'. See my edited answer for another suggestion, but it's probably still not optimal. It's a pretty interesting problem, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Your code has a missing ) in line 7. 
Here is a fixed version that loops correctly:

```
var randomOrder = [];

for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    randomOrder[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    if (i > 0) {
        while ((randomOrder.lastIndexOf(randomOrder[i], i - 1) != -1) && (((randomOrder[i - 1] - 1) != randomOrder[i]) && ((randomOrder[i - 1] + 1) != randomOrder[i]) && (randomOrder[i] != (i + 1)))) {
            randomOrder[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        }
        alert(randomOrder.lastIndexOf(randomOrder[i], i - 1));
        alert(randomOrder);
    }
}
```