# How to place 12(6 pairs) of images inside 12 <div>s randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am making a memory card game which has a structure like this,and i need to place this 6 pairs of images inside the divs randomly ,and make sure there are 2 of each and not more

heres my code i have 12 of this divs:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="frontCard">
        <img id="image0" src="images/frontCard.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="backCard">
        <img src="images/CardBack.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <div class="frontCard">
        <img id="image1" src="images/frontCard.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="backCard">
        <img src="images/CardBack.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

and js

```js
var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'images/frontCard.jpg';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'images/frontCard2.jpg';

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = 'images/frontCard3.jpg';

imgArray[3] = new Image();
imgArray[3].src = 'images/frontCard4.jpg';

imgArray[4] = new Image();
imgArray[4].src = 'images/frontCard5.jpg';

imgArray[5] = new Image();
imgArray[5].src = 'images/frontCard6.png';
max = 12;
for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {

     document.getElementById("image0").src = imgArray[Math.floor((Math.random() * 5))].src;
     //???
}
```

i have no idea how to do this in a short way without repeating myself

Comment: This might point you in the right direction:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499530/how-can-i-generate-a-random-sequence-of-numbers-in-javascript-with-conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Instead of using `document.getElementById("image0")`, you should use `document.getElementById("image" + i)` -- this way you're not just replacing the same image over and over, but instead replacing image number i.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up randomly from the image array, will result in the same image being picked twice. Instead, you can [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/2618606) the array and then just display them using a `for` loop.